# In Sitecore RTE to disable XHTML

Tags: sitecore, rich-text-editor

While adding the html in the Rich Text field the html is automatically getting formatted to validate the xhmtl markup on saving the item, how to overcome that issue, how to disable the xhmtl markup validation for the rich text fields in sitecore 9?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `Is Xhtml` validator from the four fields in the `Rich Text` field type validator. It's located here:
`/sitecore/system/Settings/Validation Rules/Field Types/Rich Text`. If you need this, you may also want to remove the xhtml validator located in the `Global Rules` item.

Comment: we have removed that already, but stil the rich text content is getting formatted.

Comment: Ok, I thought your question was about disabling the xhtml _validation_. The formatting is something completely different. In my opinion, Sitecore doesn't deal with this very well. A suitable solution is usually to make a `item:saving` processor that deals with all the formatting, making sure it uses the format you want.